# ajax and json error cannot find object elment/id

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, object

so im creating this situation where a count down happens, when it counts down to zero, a ajax post is fired off, `php`  thens returns a `json_encoded array` and i would like to loop threw this array and `.remove` things that need to be removed and `.appendTo` things that need to be added. however, i seem to have a hard time accessing an `element` from that `json object` returned from the server.... im getting `undefined` in the `console log`

jquery:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "morphelo/splash.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "x=<?=md5('countdown')?>&CountdownType="+type+"&id="+ID+"&what=<?md5('drop')?>",
                datatype: "html",
                success: function(data){ 
data = // {"19e0fa430b5a0437b87cf5bf7a365011":{"clutch-1337653726-445648193-0a6e039a028dd9a64239473ff08c82c6":"sub-clu-li**clutch-1337653726-445648193-0a6e039a028dd9a64239473ff08c82c6"}}

    var x = type.split('/');// 19e0fa430b5a0437b87cf5bf7a365011/unclock
        var m = x[0]; // 19e0fa430b5a0437b87cf5bf7a365011
    var y = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(y);
    console.log(m);
    console.log(data.m) // but it says undefinded.....          
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data.m` doesn't work, because `data` is a string.

You probably meant to access `m` in the decoded version of `data`, which you called `y`:

```
console.log(y[m]);
```

I'm using `[m]` instead of `.m` because `m` starts with numerics.

**Btw**

If you're always going to decode the HTML into JSON, you can also set the `datatype` of the `$.ajax` options to `'json'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `data[m]` instead.

`data.m` means there is a property names `m` in your object, not the content of `m`.

```
var obj = {a:1,b:2};
var m = 'a';
console.log(obj.m); // undefined
console.log(obj[m]); // 1
```